# Sharing code between Linux kernel and userspace/MCU

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux driver for an external MCU application. The driver and the MCU communicate over a bus using our own protocol.

I would like to share the program code for the protocol features between the kernel module and the MCU but since it's not possible to build a lib for the kernel my only idea so far is to write the code "as kernel as possible" and then just copy the entire .c file between the platforms.

Are there any other ways? Surly I can't be the first to want to do this.

I'm talking about code reuse, not IPC mechanisms.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't follow your question, you mean to say, some kind of data exchange mechanism like IPC, or like JSON? I didn't understand you said, you want to share the C code between MCU and kernel?

Comment: The only way for use externally compiled objects with kernel build process is *shipped* files. But, as far as I understand, those files cannot carry a code, only data. So, `write the code "as kernel as possible" and then just copy the entire .c file between the platforms.`. Such code would be needed even if kernel build process may accept precompiled code; and this would reduce only single compilation, not a space.

Comment: You could only share [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) and you probably should not share a lot of it. In general, avoid coding kernel code when possible. Your question is too broad; you should edit it to give a lot more details and context. What driver, what protocol do you have in mind?  What is an [MCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipoint_control_unit) exactly ??

Comment: For sure you can do this on Makefile level: for MCU you'll need to use cross compiler, for kernel module a native compiler. You could organize your source files in `common/`, `mcu/` and `module/` directories. Put Makefiles only in `mcu/` and `module/`. Also, I'm pretty sure that it is possible to _build a lib for kernel_ and then statically link it with module.

Comment: This might be an idea to try *if and only if* they both run same OS (Linux).

Answer (score 0):

It requires some hardware abstraction so the code implementing the protocol needs to be generic as possible not requiring any hardware specific details.
The file implementing the protocol could have functions like init, exit, read, write and interrupt. The hardware implementation itself (gpio, memory, bus) can be accessed through function pointers which are registered at time when calling the init function. The directory structure can be set up like @smbear suggested